# Cognito JWT always expired

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

When a user logs in the user gets authenticated via Cognito via the amazon-cognito-identity-js Library, the Angular App does requests to a Node JS backend where the JWT token is added to the Authorization header, the header get's parsed and validates the token via the node cognito-express SDK. Somehow the Backend always returns that the token is expired.

Angular Interceptor to Requests

```
export class CognitoInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private poolData = {
    UserPoolId: environment.cognitoUserPoolId,
    ClientId: environment.cognitoAppClientId
  }
  private userPool = new CognitoUserPool(this.poolData);
  private cognitoUser = this.userPool.getCurrentUser();
  private jwt: any;

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    this.cognitoUser?.getSession((err: any, res: CognitoUserSession) => {
      this.jwt = res.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
    });
    return next.handle(request.clone({ setHeaders: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${this.jwt}`}}));
  }
```

When checking the network tab, I see that the Token gets added.

Backend Validation:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Check that the request contains a token
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[0] === "Bearer") {
        // Validate the token
        next();

        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
        cognitoExpress.validate(token, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                // If there was an error, return a 401 Unauthorized along with the error
                res.status(401).send(err)
            } else {
                //Else API has been authenticated. Proceed.
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // If there is no token, respond appropriately 
        res.status(401).send("No token provided.")
    }
});
```

I receive from the backend:

```
{
expiredAt: "2022-04-14T08:16:19.000Z"
message: "maxAge exceeded"
name: "TokenExpiredError"
}
```

The expiredAt time is always 2 hours in the past, even when the token was created seconds ago. I could imagine it is something with different timezones even when the application is on localhost and the User Pool is the same.

Comment: *something with different timezones* - the `exp` claim (expiration time) in a JWT is a timestamp in Unix epoch time in UTC.

Comment: how do you generate the jwt?